# What is the difference between 缩减 and 削减？

Tags: meaning, difference

缩减: reduce; cut; run-down; decrement; economization; reduction; reducing; diminution; lessening; impansion:

削减: cut (down); reduce; slash; whittle down:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

缩 = shrink; 缩减 = shrink / reduce

削 = cut; 削减 = cut / reduce

> **缩减預算** you can **shrink the a budget** to reduce it's size. (budget as a whole shrinks )
>
> **削减預算** you can cut the budget to reduce it's size (sum of money or items in the budget being cut away)

~

> **缩减開支** you can **shrink expenditures** to reduce it's amount (expenditures as a whole shrinks )
>
> **削减開支** you **can cut the expenditures** to reduce it's amount. (sum of money or items in the expenditures be cut away)

~

> **削减僱員** you can **cut employees** to reduce your company size. (individual employees being cut away)
>
> **缩减僱員** you cannot **shrink employees**  ;  you can only **缩减僱員人數** (shrink the number of employees)